# How to update variable every full hour without refresh page by user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Controller:

```
$number = rand(1, 100);
```

View:

```
<div id="lucky">
   Your lucky number: <?php echo $number ?>.
</div>
```

How can I update the value for `$number` every hour without manually refreshing the page? I can use `setInterval` from *JavaScript/jQuery*, but I would like do it exactly at full hour (0:00, 1:00, 2:00 etc...). What is the best way to do this? I can use PHP, CRON, JS and JS frameworks...

Comment: You want to use Ajax,

Comment: I know but how to change it at full hours? I don't want to start my application at full hour to start setInterval.

Comment: Just curious, for which use case is this needed?

Comment: Exact timekeeping is not possible with JavaScript. Best you can do is set an interval for every minute (or less) and check whether you've hit the hour mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var d = new Date();

var firstTrigger = 60000* (60 - d.getMinutes());

// This is for 1st Time Trigger
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("1st time trigger", rand(1, 100));
  
  // This is continuous trigger every full hour
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Continuous trigger every hour", rand(1, 100));
  }, 3600000);
}, firstTrigger);
```

In your case, instead of `console.log` you will trigger your code.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try  finding  out what time it is now, figure out how long it is until the next full hour, then wait that long:

```
function doSomething() {
    var d = new Date(),
        h = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours() + 1, 0, 0, 0),
        e = h - d;
    if (e > 100) { // some arbitrary time period
        window.setTimeout(doSomething, e);
    }
    // your code(May be an ajax call to show lucky num)
}
```

The check for e < 100 is just to make sure you don't do setTimeout on something like 5 ms and get it a crazy loop.